# Wavelet Tresholding on R

Tags: r, wavelet-transform

One way to remove noise from a signal is applying the discrete wavelet transform, apply a threshold (soft or hard) and then run the inverse discrete wavelet transform to retrieve the original signal without noise.

R language has dwt and idwt functions (package wavelets) to perform the discrete wavelet transform and inverse discrete wavelet transform. The output of dwt is W (wavelet coefficient) and V (scale coefficient).

My question is: The threshold should be applied on W, on V or both? And why? I'm missing something here because for me should be on W, but it didnt work.

Example:

```
library(wavelets)
w <- dwt(series_with_noise, filter="la16")
w@W$W1 <- treshold_function(w@W$W1, lambda) # Should I do this?
w@V$V1 <- treshold_function(w@V$V1, lambda) # Should I do this?
series_denoised <- idwt(w)
plot(series_denoised)
```

If I nullify all w@W but maintaining V the idwt doesnt change. Don't know why =/.

Comment: You should tell us which package contains those functions, and show us a simplified version of your code.

Comment: We don't know what `treshold_function` is doing.  I'll assume it's a hard threshold: `treshold_function <- function(x, lambda) { x[abs(x) < lambda] <- 0; x }`.  Then you should apply it to the `W` coefficients, perhaps to more levels than just level 1.

Comment: I write on text that this threshold is hard or soft. 

If you could try this code using a null function in threshold and applying only on W. For me if I nullify everything on W , maintaining V, and do the inverse discrete wavelet transform the plot doesnt change =/

Comment: That's not what I see.  If I multiply all the W vectors by 0 (so it keeps their length the same), then invert the transform, I get a fairly smooth result.  It's not flat, because the last V entry is still used.  In my case I had 512 observations, and I nullified W1 to W6.  There were no higher W vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You should modify the W values if you want to do smoothing.  For example:

```r
set.seed(123)
t <- seq(0, 2*pi, len = 512)
x <- sin(t) + rnorm(512)
plot(t, x)

library(wavelets)
wt <- dwt(x, filter = "la16")

names(wt@W)
#> [1] "W1" "W2" "W3" "W4" "W5"
wt@W$W1 <- 0*wt@W$W1
wt@W$W2 <- 0*wt@W$W2
wt@W$W3 <- 0*wt@W$W3
wt@W$W4 <- 0*wt@W$W4
wt@W$W5 <- 0*wt@W$W5

y <- idwt(wt)
lines(t, y, lwd=3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>